# Saving report layouts as template (.qpt) using QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, print-composer, reports

I am trying to develop a Report Layout that can be used with multiple .QGS files. A Map (print composer) layout can be saved as a template file (.qpt) but this option is greyed-out for Report Layouts.

Is there any way to export report layouts or otherwise move them between projects?

I am using QGIS 3.22

Answer (score 0):

As [commented by @RainForest](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/460598/qgis-save-report-layouts-as-template-qpt#comment752336_460598):

> ... this option is grey for [am] empty report and [only becomes]
> available after adding any objects.